# Is it acceptable to link to a specific question that I think should be flagged?

Tags: discussion

I have been down voted a couple times for asking a broad question that I think is fine--a few times, so I keep going back to make changes until it's a better question. I'm bringing that up to point out that I don't always know when something is too broad.

That being said, is it acceptable to ask DBA-meta what they think as well as include a link to the question in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, meta is the place to ask.

From [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

> Meta is for...
>
> ...Database Administrators Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other about Database Administrators Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)

If you want feedback about a specific question, naturally you should link to it.